# How to decompress pvr to raw format 8888 in c++?

Tags: c++, opengl-es

Im looking for informations, how to uncompress pvr data to raw format like 8888.

For png there is libpng, for jpeg is libjpeg, is there something for pvr?

I dont want to use compressed texture in OpenGL (i have my reasons).

I know how to get infomation from header data, but how to uncompress image data from pvr?

Comment: "I dont want to use compressed texture in OpenGL (i have my reasons)." If you don't want to use the textures compressed... why did you compress them? And if *you* didn't compress them, who did, and why can't you tell them to decompress them with their tools?

Comment: I want to use this same assets for many devices, some of them dont have feature to draw compressed textures

Comment: The way it's generally done is to have an asset conditioning pipeline that generates the correct assets for each platform. That's going to work a lot better than decompressing compressed textures, since at least on those platforms you don't get compression artifacts.

Comment: Thats true, but I want to have that support, that is more safe.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can find source code to decompress PVR texture in Imagination PowerVR OpenGL ES SDK located here: http://www.imgtec.com/powervr/insider/sdk/KhronosOpenGLES2xSGX.asp

You'll need following source files:

- PVRTDecompress.h/cpp
- PVRTTexture.h/cpp
- PVRTGlobal.h

Alternatively look at source code in [oolongengine](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/) - it uses same source code to decompress PVR textures:

- [Texture.h](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/source/browse/trunk/Oolong%20Engine2/Renderer/Core/GraphicsDevice/Texture.h)
- [Texture.mm](http://code.google.com/p/oolongengine/source/browse/trunk/Oolong%20Engine2/Renderer/Core/GraphicsDevice/Texture.mm)

Comment: Only oolongengine link is alive at the moment.